# Prove $\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{5}-2\cos{x}}dx=\frac{\pi^3}{15}+2\pi\ln^2{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}$ without contour integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> Show that
>   $$\int_{0}^{\pi}\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{5}-2\cos{x}}dx=\dfrac{\pi^3}{15}+2\pi\ln^2{\left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)}$$

[This thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/502007/89121) demonstrates how contour integration can be used to solve the above integral, but I'm interested in finding alternative methods.

I believe one might utilize the [Polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) in some way. My attempt: I tried to rely on the identity
$$2\cos{x}=e^{ix}+e^{-ix}.$$

Can someone think of a solution to this integral which doesn't involve the residue theorem?

Thank you

Comment: Just a random idea, but would the Taylor series of $\cos x$ be any help?

Comment: FWIW The integral has a singularity at $x=i\log\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ so it's just a matter of finding the right contour...

Comment: @math110 Why do you think that you can find a solution without complex integration?

Comment: @user37238: Feynman loved to tell people that he could do any integral that his MIT friends could do using contour integration techniques.  I would just love to sick this one on him.

Comment: [It was solved here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/502824/85343)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, this question explicitly ask for a solution that didn't use residue. Unless someone produce a solution to the other question that didn't use residue, this should not be closed.

Comment: @RonGordon It's deleted. Recently, I found you already solved while I was trying a slightly  different approach. However, I think it will be sometimes deleted forever.Thanks.

Comment: why closed it? Thank you for explain?

Comment: I evaluated the integral in the other thread without using contour integration.